# How to correctly format i % 2 == 0 in bison grammar?

Tags: bison

I have grammar that contains:

```
expression : NUMBER { $$ = new Int($1); }
       | identifier { $$ = $<expr>1; }
       | INC identifier { $$ = new UnaryOperation($<expr>2, O_ADD_BEFORE); }
       | identifier INC { $$ = new UnaryOperation($<expr>1, O_ADD_AFTER); }
       | DEC identifier { $$ = new UnaryOperation($<expr>2, O_SUB_BEFORE); }
       | identifier DEC { $$ = new UnaryOperation($<expr>1, O_SUB_AFTER); }
       | PLUS expression { $$ = $<expr>1; }
       | MINUS expression { $$ = new UnaryOperation($<expr>2, O_UNARY_MINUS); }
       | LNEG expression { $$ = new UnaryOperation($<expr>2, O_LOG_NEG); }
       | BNEG expression { $$ = new UnaryOperation($<expr>2, O_BIT_NEG); }
       | expression PLUS expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_PLUS); }
       | expression MINUS expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_MINUS); }
       | expression MUL expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_MUL); }
       | expression DIV expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_DIV); }
       | expression SHIFTL expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_SHIFT_LEFT); }
       | expression SHIFTR expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_SHIFT_RIGHT); }
       | expression LESS expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_LESS); }
       | expression MORE expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_MORE); }
       | expression LESS_EQ expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_LESS_EQ); }
       | expression MORE_EQ expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_MORE_EQ); }
       | expression BAND expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_BIT_AND); }
       | expression BOR expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_BIT_OR); }
       | expression BXOR expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_BIT_XOR); }
       | expression EQ expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_EQUALS); }
       | expression NEQ expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_NEQUALS); }
       | expression OR expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_LOG_OR); }
       | expression AND expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_LOG_AND); }
       | expression MOD expression { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>1, $<expr>3, O_MOD); }
       | LEFT_BRACE set_expr RIGHT_BRACE { $$ = $<expr>1; }
       | LEFT_BRACE identifier SET_MUL expression RIGHT_BRACE { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>2, $<expr>4, O_SET_MUL); }
       | LEFT_BRACE identifier SET_DIV expression RIGHT_BRACE { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>2, $<expr>4, O_SET_DIV); }
       | LEFT_BRACE identifier SET_MOD expression RIGHT_BRACE { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>2, $<expr>4, O_SET_MOD); }
       | LEFT_BRACE identifier SET_ADD expression RIGHT_BRACE { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>2, $<expr>4, O_SET_ADD); }
       | LEFT_BRACE identifier SET_SUB expression RIGHT_BRACE { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>2, $<expr>4, O_SET_SUB); }
       | LEFT_BRACE identifier SET_SHIFT_L expression RIGHT_BRACE { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>2, $<expr>4, O_SET_SHIFT_L); }
       | LEFT_BRACE identifier SET_SHIFT_R expression RIGHT_BRACE { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>2, $<expr>4, O_SET_SHIFT_R); }
       | LEFT_BRACE identifier SET_AND expression RIGHT_BRACE { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>2, $<expr>4, O_SET_AND); }
       | LEFT_BRACE identifier SET_XOR expression RIGHT_BRACE { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>2, $<expr>4, O_SET_XOR); }
       | LEFT_BRACE identifier SET_OR expression RIGHT_BRACE { $$ = new BinaryOperation($<expr>2, $<expr>4, O_SET_OR); }
       | LEFT_BRACE expression RIGHT_BRACE { $$ = $2; }
       ;
```

however when I compile my tree into bytecode, expression

```
i % 2 == 0
```

will end with this order of operation:

```
PUSH i
PUSH 2
PUSH 0
EQ
MOD
```

which is not correct. How can I force the tree of the parser to make operation i % 2 first then do i % 2 == 0?

Comment: Parentheses exist for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare to bison that `MOD` has greater precedence than `EQ`:

```
%left EQ
%left MOD
```

This must be done after the declaration of your tokens.

Comment: So precedence is based on the order of the tokens or the order of %left s?

Comment: The order of lefts. You can put multiple tokens in a left. But does it solve  your problem?